# how to secure anchor links on live server HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, websecurity

I am creating website which has multiple webpages with multiple anchor tags/links like

```
<a href="index.php">home</a>
```

i just want to secure these anchor links from manipulations by hackers like any kind of security attack. is there any way to escape from this vulnerablity?

Comment: If your code is exactly as shown, I don't think you are vulnerable to any attacks. If the link comes from a variable that a user has the ability to change, you may be vulnerable to XSS injection attacks.

Comment: Well, attacks on links are possible. For instance a [Denial-of-service attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). Do you want to protect against this, or did you have something else in mind? A DoS attack is not a real "manipulation", nothing in your site, or on your server, is changed.

Comment: yeah like everything which is posible in anyway .because pages may have sensitive data.

Comment: a `hyperlink` like that does not pose a security threat in itself - once the browser loads the webpage the user can manipulate the HTML in whatever way they wish and there is nothing you can do to prevent that ~ it remains HTML in their browser only.

Comment: Make sure the anchors are heavy enough, so they won't be swept away if there's a tsunami of packets coming in. Seriously though, unless you do anything dynamic about generating your links you're fine, straight-up HTML is safe as is. Otherwise, if malicious parties can access your server to modify static resources, you have bigger problems than your anchors floating around.